# What do you think about Mobile Robotics Programming Toolkit?

Tags: toolkit, robotics

Did anyone use [Mobile Robotics Programming Toolkit](http://www.mrpt.org/)? What do you think about it?
I am currently studying the SLAM problem (I am quite new in this area) and I am planning to implement a Mono Slam solution based on Extended Kalman Filter (C++). Do you recommend to implement my solution on top of Mobile Robotics Programming Toolkit, or it would be better to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd say it depends. Why would you use it? Does it provide anything special that you need, like feature extraction or visualization? Since it's for learning purposes, I'm assume their monoslam implementation is of little interest.

If not, why bother? Once you have your measurements, you pretty much only need a decent linear algebra library. I recommend [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page); it's easy to use and does everything you need.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't actually used MRPT.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Eigen is also included in MRPT. I am starting to use MRPT as well. It's quite a good tool for SLAM beginner->advanced I think.